RigidBody does not bounce
tech support - open
I am making a game where you place objects in specific placements so that they together do something. The ball which I use ass an prototype just does not work always and just bounces sometimes.
The code of the ball:
extends RigidBody2D
@onready var area_2d = $Area2D

var dragging = false
var of = Vector2(0,0)
@onready var button = $"../Button"
func _integrate_forces( body_state ):
if is_using_custom_integrator() :
    body_state.set_linear_velocity( Vector2(0,0) )
    body_state.set_angular_velocity( 0 )

func _ready():

set_freeze_enabled(true)
func _on_button_pressed():
set_freeze_enabled(false)
func _on_area_2d_body_entered(body):

if "Floor" in body.name:
    linear_velocity.y = -linear_velocity.y/1.2

func _process(_delta):
if dragging:
    position = get_global_mouse_position() - of
func _on_button_button_down():
dragging = true
of = get_global_mouse_position() - global_position
set_freeze_enabled(true)

func _on_button_button_up():
dragging = false

pictures:
r/godot - Game scene
r/godot - ball scene
I have tried using a character body and a rigid body.
